# How to maintain user's session in ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on migrating the existing ASP.NET application to MVC.
Earlier we used to maintain the user sessions and can be accessed in whatever page we want.

Ex:  Session["UserType"] = var_UserMastersBO.UserType.ToString();

We set this session Global.asax file.

In case if there are restricted pages based on the userType, we check this if condition in the page load.

Cal we implement the same in MVC?

Appreciate your responses.
Thanks

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Im new to this site.
Could you please tell me?

Comment: You should accept answers when they satisfy your question don't let your questions hang !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is built on top of the ASP.NET so you can use every feature of ASP.NET like Session Membership Caching in MVC.

Comment: Yeah, as ali says, all this stuff is the same.  You can use the global.asax in the same way too.